# How do mass and momentum travel in wave?

Tags: waves, momentum, mass, acoustics, continuum-mechanics

In my book what i read was ; In transverse wave - Only Energy is transferred (not Momentum and mass) while in longitudinal wave - Energy , mass and Momentum are  transferred.   [ Note : The above waves considered are Mechanical ones] . So I need an explanation to this , like what actually is the reason behind this if the above mentioned statement in my book is right.  If not what is the right one? I need a detailed explanation. Hope someone will help me with it.

Comment: I would suggest that you invest in another book as a travelling wave transfers both energy and momentum.

Answer (score 3):

A water wave is transverse, but if you placed a rubber ball over it, clearly the ball moves up and down too, bobbing as the water waves disperse. Clearly, that's momentum and energy transferred to the ball from the oscillating water molecules.

Same thing with longitudinal waves. When sound waves move through air, the air molecules move because they were just imparted momentum from the passing waves. Ultimately, the energy is transferred in a wave with contact by the neighboring atom in these cases (longitudinal and transverse). And if energy is transferred, the atoms are then displaced, they just gained momentum in this process. Waves do this all the time. It's fundamental physics.

Answer (score 0):

"Wave momentum" is a messy subject when waves are travelling in a medium or on a string. You need to understand the difference between momentum and psuedo-momentum.  A good place to read this is in Michael McIntyre's [On the ‘wave momentum’ myth](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0022112081001626). Sadly this is paywalled.  An  acount for sound waves is in [my old paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9909315)